# What is the reason for error while using abi compliance checker?

Tags: c++, compatibility, abi

I am using [abi compliance checker](https://github.com/lvc/abi-compliance-checker) to check the compatibility of two libraries.
I am getting given error:

```
preparation, please wait ...
ERROR: the input dump d1 is invalid
```

Command used:

```
abi-compliance-checker -l libtest -old ABIv0.dump -new ABIv1.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open the `ABIv0.dump` in a text editor and look at the `SymbolsInfo` section. It's probably empty. This indicates that your ABI dump contains no info on symbols to compare.

Does you library contain any public ABI symbols?

Use `abi-dumper -extra-info ./extra` command to dump debug info of your library to the `./extra` directory (see https://github.com/lvc/abi-dumper).

Also please upgrade to the latest 2.0 version of the tool for better analysis.